# [A]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cannot be cast to [B]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Type A originates from 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0

Tags: json.net, azure-functions

I am using `Microsoft.Azure.Devices` for get iot devices from cloud. Using below code I'm getting error

**newton.json**

```
var device = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
foreach (Twin twin in device)
{}
```

1. Using azure function v2.0 same code was working (no error).
2. Using azure function v1.0 same code I got error.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package still has the dependency on the older version of the package. If you create a Function Project you cannot use any other Nuget Packages that have a dependency on `Newtonsoft.Json` version which is higher than the function runtime dependent version.

I have faced this earlier and made a small blog [here](https://medium.com/@hharan618/common-issues-while-development-of-azure-functions-76b08299af58) about most of the issues